# Visual Studio 2017 SDK location is not changable

Tags: visual-studio

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niAmp.png)
When I try to install VS2017 Community, SDK location is set in D drive, which is my external HDD drive. I want to install this in my other SSD drive(not C drive) but install location is always unchangable. Dont know how to solve this. Try to force delete, CMD, and uninstall-reinstall over and over. Need serious help.

Comment: I'm afraid my Korean is a little rusty. ;)

Comment: If uninstall reinstall really doesn't work, I guess the path must be saved in the registry somewhere?

Comment: then where can I get that registry location for vs2017??